# What parameters do I need to meet in order to change my Druid’s spells for the day?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, druid

I've started a game in Pathfinder, as a Druid.

Like any other spell caster, Druids need to rest in order to replenish their spell uses. However, Druids "know" all the spells in the Druid spell list —they are just required to prepare a limited amount per day.

In the game, we came across a scenario where my PC was being chased, and was therefore preoccupied, as the sun rose. Obviously, he couldn't really stop and prepare anything at that given time, and so we said that I was “stuck” with my current list of spells, until next time.

So, as a Druid, what do I need in terms of “when”, and “how long”, to prepare my spells for the day?

Comment: I specified Druid in your title because different spellcasters have different requirements for their daily preparation. If you intended to have a more comprehensive answer including other casters, you can re-edit to include that.

Comment: @Ifusaso that's fair, though I did specify it in the question itself :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Druid (Spells)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid) indicates:

> A druid must spend 1 hour each day in a trance-like meditation on the mysteries of nature to regain her daily allotment of spells. A druid may prepare and cast any spell on the druid spell list, provided that she can cast spells of that level, but she must choose which spells to prepare during her daily meditation.

It doesn't matter to a Druid when they spend an hour meditating, only that they may only do it once per day. When you've completed being chased or otherwise found an hour to yourself, you can refresh your spell slots and change which spells you've selected.

Answer (score 2):

[Preparing divine spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Preparing-Divine-Spells) says:

> Time of Day
>
> A divine spellcaster chooses and prepares spells ahead of time, but unlike a wizard, does not require a period of rest to prepare spells. Instead, the character chooses a particular time of day to pray and receive spells. The time is usually associated with some daily event. If some event prevents a character from praying at the proper time, she must do so as soon as possible. If the character does not stop to pray for spells at the first opportunity, she must wait until the next day to prepare spells.

So you don't have complete freedom about when to prepare spells. But being in the middle of an emergency is sufficient excuse; your god will understand and let you postpone it a little.

Picking "dawn" as the time for your daily ritual is entirely reasonable, but not forced by the rules. And no, you don't need to sleep.